# Show $A =\{x\in \ell_2 : |x_n|\le\frac{1}{n}\},n=1,2,...$ is a closed set in $\ell_2$ but $B=\{x\in \ell_2 :|x_n|< \frac{1}{n}\}$ is not an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that the set $A =\{x\in \ell_2 : |x_n|\le\frac{1}{n},n=1,2,...\}$ is a closed set in $\ell_2$ but that $B=\{x\in \ell_2 :|x_n|< \frac{1}{n}\}$ is not an open set.

I think if I show each $A_n=\{x\in\ell_2,|x_n|\le\frac{1}{n}\}$ is closed, I can get $A=\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}A_n$ that is closed. Can I do that? However, I didn't know how to prove $A_n=\{x\in\ell_2,|x_n|\le\frac{1}{n}\}$ is closed.

Are there any other ways to prove this?

Comment: Actually, you could even show that no $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ is contained in $B$.

Comment: @arkeet, That seems much easier. Thank you!

Comment: I only learned the definition of closed set, some equivalent conditions and some related concepts such as limit point. So, I don't understand this. Do you have a more elementary method?

Comment: Since the topology of $\ell_2$ is given by metric (so that $\ell_2$ is first-countable), a subset $F \subseteq \ell_2$ is closed if and only if every sequence in $F$ that converges has a limit in $F$. Also observe that convergence in $\ell_2$ implies coordinate-wise convergence. So if you have a sequence $\{ x^{(k)} \}_{k \geq 1}$ in $A$ which converges to $x$ in $\ell_2$, you must have $$ \lim_{k\to\infty} x_n^{(k)} = x_n \quad \forall n = 1, 2, \cdots. $$ Can you conclude that $|x_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and consequently $x \in A$?

Comment: @SangchulLee I think we can conclude this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SangchulLee comment convergence in $\ell_2$ implies coordinate wise converge, therefore $x_n\overset{\ell_2}\rightarrow x$ implies that for all $k:x_n^{(k)}$ converges to $x^k$ in $\mathbb R$.

Now the point is that $|{x}|\leq \frac 1 n$ is a closed set, therefore if $|x_n^{(k)}|\leq \frac 1 k$ and it converges the limit element will also satisfy $|x^{(k)}|\leq\frac 1 k$ and so it effectively lies in $A$.

For the second case you have that $x_n^{(k)}<\frac 1 k$ which is an open condition so that the limit can escape. For example you can take the sequence: $$x_n=\begin{cases} 1-\frac 1 n,\quad k=1\\0\end{cases}$$

this is clearly in $B$ bu the limit is the sequence $(1,0,0,\dotsc)$ which does not lie in $B$.

Answer (score -1):

You could try showing it's the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map.

Comment: You could be more specific.